# Google News scrapper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get news titles from google. So far, I am using the GoogleNews API and I have this code:

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd

googlenews = GoogleNews(start='01/01/2022', end='31/12/2022')
googlenews.search('Apple')
result = googlenews.result()
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df.head())

for i in range(2,50):
    googlenews.getpage(i)
    result = googlenews.result()
    df = df.append(result)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['title'], keep='last')
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

And it works, the code gives me around 234 news. But, I would like to know if there is a way to get even more news, for example 400.

I have tried some other libraries but they only return up to 100 search results. So I'd like to know if there is another API or way of getting more results.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pagination](https://github.com/Iceloof/GoogleNews):

> Default return first page result, you don't need to get first page again, otherwise you might get duplicate result. To get other page of search results:
>
> ```
> googlenews.get_page(2)
> ```